# Cant able to remove selected item from the array then push it to the new array so that the quote never repeats

Tags: javascript

https://github.com/Rishabh-Ahuja/Random-Quote-Generator

what iam trying to do is to do something that a quote when shown never repeats 
so i tried removing the selected / shown quote from the array and adding it to another array then after the array is undefined then again pushing all items to the original array . But iam unable to do so . PLease help

Comment: Could you paste your js here?

Comment: `otherList.push(mainList.splice(index, 1))` is the core code you want to remove an item from the main array and put it in another array (or you could simply shuffle your array then do `other.push(main.pop())`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following script shows in console quotes randomly picked up every one second. 
The script show a random quote only once, as after a quote has been displayed it is removed from the original quotes array.

Use [Array.prototype.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) for removing an element from an array at a specific index. Yo do not need to create a second array as mentioned in your question.

You can use this principal in your implementation, below an example:

```js
(function() {
  var arrayQ = [{
    quote: "The material world is a dangerous place to be in. It's dangerous because there is a temptation of illusory energy; there is danger at every step.",
    source: "HH GOPAL KRISHNA GOSWAMI",
    citation: "ISKCON DESIRE TREE",
    year: 2016
  }, {
    quote: "If you carry out the order of your spiritual master then the Lord will be so pleased that He will come to see you.",
    source: "HH GOPAL KRISHNA GOSWAMI",
    citation: "ISKCON DESIRE TREE",
    year: 2013
  }, {
    quote: "Our vaccination is chanting the names of Krishna, Hearing the Bhagavad-gita and Srimad Bhagavatam, and thinking of Krishna all the time.",
    source: "HH GOPAL KRISHNA GOSWAMI",
    citation: "ISKCON DESIRE TREE",
    year: 2003
  }, {
    quote: "Vairagya means that when the opportunity for sense gratification is there, I voluntarily abstain from it.",
    source: "HH GOPAL KRISHNA GOSWAMI",
    citation: "ISKCON DESIRE TREE",
    year: 2006
  }, {
    quote: "Our quota is not sixteen rounds, but attentive sixteen rounds.",
    source: "HH GOPAL KRISHNA GOSWAMI",
    citation: "ISKCON DESIRE TREE",
    year: 2009
  }, {
    quote: "Guru is pleased when he sees that the disciple is showing the symptoms of Shudh Bhakti.",
    source: "HH GOPAL KRISHNA GOSWAMI",
    citation: "ISKCON DESIRE TREE",
    year: 2010
  }, {
    quote: "Devotional service is so simple, but devotees because of their material inclinations make it complicated.",
    source: "HH GOPAL KRISHNA GOSWAMI",
    citation: "ISKCON DESIRE TREE",
    year: 2011
  }, {
    quote: "Whatever we give to Krishna that will be remembered eternally, that will be appreciated eternally.",
    source: "HH GOPAL KRISHNA GOSWAMI"
  }, ];

  var randomQuotes = function() {
    var getRandomInt = function(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
      },
      index = getRandomInt(0, arrayQ.length),
      quote = arrayQ[index];
    if (quote) {
      console.log(quote);
      arrayQ.splice(index, 1);// remove quote from array
    }
  };
  setInterval(function() {
    randomQuotes()
  }, 1000);
})();
```

Comment: why did u use max min u can only use arrayq.length  and it only removes the quote but how will add it when the arrayq is empty